# Parent / Child in same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have table structure like below:

```
id |parent|name |value
1  | 0    | aaa |
2  | 0    | bbb |
3  | 0    | ccc |
4  | 1    |     | 111
5  | 1    |     | 222
6  | 3    |     | 333
```

I want to display parent if it has child records.

Like:

(parent id + name + value first child)

```
1 - aaa - 111
3 - ccc - 333
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no meaning of the first child in the database, you can get the first child by the mininum of the `id` or the minimum of the value, but the values are not stored with a specific order in the table, so you can't tell which value is the first one.

But, assuming that the `id` is auto incremental column, then value of the first child is the value of the minimum `id`, then you can do this:

```
SELECT
  t1.parent,
  t2.name,
  t1.value
FROM tablename AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT MIN(id) AS id, parent
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY parent
) AS t22 ON t22.id = t1.id AND t1.parent = t22.parent
INNER JOIN tablename AS t2 ON t1.parent = t2.id;
```

See it in action here:

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/834637/11)

This will give you :

```
| PARENT | NAME | VALUE |
-------------------------
|      1 |  aaa |   111 |
|      3 |  ccc |   333 |
```

---

**Or:** You can get it by the minimum value:

```
SELECT
  t1.parent,
  t2.name,
  MIN(t1.value) AS value
FROM tablename AS t1
INNER JOIN tablename AS t2 ON t1.parent = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.parent, t2.name;
```

See it in action:

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/834637/2)

This will give you:

```
| PARENT | NAME | VALUE |
-------------------------
|      1 |  aaa |   111 |
|      3 |  ccc |   333 |
```