# How to join table and retrieve records containing either parent or child info, but not both?

Tags: sql, postgresql

all,

I need help with finding query for a complicated situation.

Assume I have the following db structure (made up to resemble what we currently have):

**reservations**

```
booking_code | description
-------------+-------------
alpha        | alpha code
beta         | beta code
gamma        | gamma code
omega        | omega code
```

**guests**

```
name        | booking_code   | parent_booking_code
------------+----------------+----------------------
andrew      | alpha          | -
kelvin      | beta           | -
michael     | -              | beta
nancy       | -              | beta
olaf        | gamma          | -
patricia    | -              | gamma
quincy      | -              | omega
raphael     | kappa          | -
stanley     | -              | kappa
timmy       | -              | delta
```

SQL query to create the above:

```
CREATE TABLE reservations (
   booking_code VARCHAR(15),
   description VARCHAR(15)
);

INSERT INTO reservations VALUES
('alpha', 'alpha code'), ('beta', 'beta code'), ('gamma', 'gamma code'), ('omega', 'omega code') ;

CREATE TABLE guests (
    name VARCHAR(20),
    booking_code VARCHAR(15),
    parent_booking_code VARCHAR(15)
);

INSERT INTO guests VALUES
('andrew', 'alpha', '-'), ('kelvin', 'beta', '-'), ('michael', '-', 'beta'), ('nancy', '-', 'beta'),
('olaf', 'gamma', '-'), ('patricia', '-', 'gamma'), ('quincy', '-', 'omega'), ('raphael', 'kappa', '-'),
('stanley', '-', 'kappa'), ('timmy', '-', 'delta') ;
```

From here, I need to find out at least one person having the `booking_code` or `parent_booking_code` specified under `reservations`. I want to avoid duplicate booking code, so if one person has the `booking_code` already, do not look for others with same `parent_booking_code`, and vice versa.

Based on the above information, I need to find:

```
   name   | code
----------+-------
 andrew   | alpha
 kelvin   | beta
 olaf     | gamma
 quincy   | omega
```

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT
    guests.name,
    reservations.booking_code AS code
FROM
    reservations
JOIN
    guests ON
        reservations.booking_code = guests.booking_code OR
        reservations.booking_code = guests.parent_booking_code

GROUP BY name, code
ORDER BY name ;

/*
   name   | code
----------+-------
 andrew   | alpha
 kelvin   | beta
 michael  | beta
 nancy    | beta
 olaf     | gamma
 patricia | gamma
 quincy   | omega
(7 rows)
*/
```

Trial 2:

```
SELECT
    guests.name,
    reservations.booking_code AS code
FROM
    reservations
JOIN
    guests ON
        reservations.booking_code = guests.booking_code
JOIN
    guests AS g2 ON
        reservations.booking_code = g2.parent_booking_code

GROUP BY guests.name, code
ORDER BY guests.name ;

/*
  name  | code
--------+-------
 andrew | alpha
 kelvin | beta
 olaf   | gamma
        |
(4 rows)
*/
```

Trial 3 (adapted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854086/parent-child-in-same-table)):

```
SELECT
    reservations.booking_code AS code,
    g1.name
FROM
    reservations
JOIN
    guests AS g1 ON
        reservations.booking_code = g1.booking_code
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT name, parent_booking_code
        FROM guests
        GROUP BY name, parent_booking_code
    )
    AS g2 ON
        g2.name = g1.name AND g2.parent_booking_code = g1.parent_booking_code
INNER JOIN
    guests AS g3 ON
        g1.parent_booking_code = g3.booking_code

GROUP BY g1.name, code
ORDER BY g1.name ;

/*
 code  |  name
-------+--------
 alpha | andrew
 beta  | kelvin
 gamma | olaf
(3 rows)
*/
```

I tried to borrow from the solution found [on this forum](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/sql-select-help-please), but I couldn't figure out a way to apply it to my situation since in that example, the "code" is specified in the query (`parent_id`), while in my case it's part of entries inside the `reservations` table.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Additional note: We're using postgresql if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple query:

```
SELECT
    MIN(guests.name) AS name,
    reservations.booking_code AS code
FROM
    reservations
JOIN
    guests ON
        reservations.booking_code = guests.booking_code OR
        reservations.booking_code = guests.parent_booking_code
GROUP BY code
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: Wow. Never thought of using `MIN()` to get one name out of multiple possible names. It actually works. :)