# How to join table with parent/child columns inside, and retrieve only rows with matching parent or child, but not both (part 2)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is a follow up on the [question I posted last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180181/how-to-join-table-and-retrieve-records-containing-either-parent-or-child-info-b).

Summary of previous question:
I want to join two tables, and pick up the person having either `booking_code` or `parent_booking_code` and display the result.

After several attempts at implementing the answer into our code, we found out that we also want to put the priority on the person having `booking_code`. That is to say, if we have the following table and data (with the entries for 'kelvin' and 'michael' different from before):

**reservations**

```
booking_code | description
-------------+-------------
alpha        | alpha code
beta         | beta code
gamma        | gamma code
omega        | omega code
```

**guests** (note: `-` means `NULL`)

```
name        | booking_code   | parent_booking_code
------------+----------------+----------------------
andrew      | alpha          | -
kelvin      | -              | beta             ***
michael     | beta           | -                ***
nancy       | -              | beta
olaf        | gamma          | -
patricia    | -              | gamma
quincy      | -              | omega
raphael     | kappa          | -
stanley     | -              | kappa
timmy       | -              | delta
```

**Expected output**:
We want the query to give us:

```
   name   | code
----------+-------
 andrew   | alpha
 michael  | beta
 olaf     | gamma
 quincy   | omega
```

[Previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25185489/1457788) would give the name `kelvin` for the code `beta`, as we are picking the person having the "smallest" name.

Here's one of the things we tried, which didn't give us `andrew - alpha`:

```
SELECT
    g.name,
    reservations.booking_code AS code
FROM
(
    SELECT *, booking_code AS bc
    FROM guests AS g1
    WHERE booking_code IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT parent_booking_code FROM guests WHERE parent_booking_code IS NOT NULL)
    UNION
    SELECT *, parent_booking_code AS bc
    FROM guests AS g2
    WHERE parent_booking_code NOT IN (SELECT booking_code FROM guests WHERE booking_code IS NOT NULL)
) AS g

JOIN
    reservations ON
        g.bc = reservations.booking_code ;

/*
  name   | code  
---------+-------
 olaf    | gamma
 quincy  | omega
 michael | beta
(3 rows)
*/
```

It might be because we're not doing `UNION` with records having `booking_code` without corresponding `parent_booking_code`. However, we thought if we add that in, the `UNION` would be big and it will be very slow.

We also tried this, but could not figure out how to filter the records by distinct code:

```
SELECT
    guests.name AS name,
    guests.combo_code AS code,
    MIN(guests.ranking) AS rank
FROM
    reservations
JOIN
    (SELECT 
        COALESCE (booking_code, parent_booking_code) AS combo_code,
        CASE WHEN booking_code IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 2
        END AS ranking,
        guests.*
     FROM guests
    ) AS guests ON
        guests.combo_code = reservations.booking_code
GROUP BY name, code
ORDER BY rank, name;
/*
   name   | code  | rank 
----------+-------+------
 andrew   | alpha |    1
 michael  | beta  |    1
 olaf     | gamma |    1
 kelvin   | beta  |    2
 nancy    | beta  |    2
 patricia | gamma |    2
 quincy   | omega |    2
(7 rows)
 */
```

SQL query to create the table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE reservations (
   booking_code VARCHAR(15),
   description VARCHAR(15)
);

INSERT INTO reservations VALUES
('alpha', 'alpha code'), ('beta', 'beta code'), ('gamma', 'gamma code'), ('omega', 'omega code') ;

CREATE TABLE guests (
    name VARCHAR(20),
    booking_code VARCHAR(15),
    parent_booking_code VARCHAR(15)
);

INSERT INTO guests VALUES
('andrew', 'alpha', NULL), ('kelvin', NULL, 'beta'), ('michael', 'beta', NULL), ('nancy', NULL, 'beta'),
('olaf', 'gamma', NULL), ('patricia', NULL, 'gamma'), ('quincy', NULL, 'omega'), ('raphael', 'kappa', NULL),
('stanley', NULL, 'kappa'), ('timmy', NULL, 'delta') ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's remove GROUP BY, ORDER BY and the aggregate from the solution that was offered in your last question, and add an extra field to the projection, that tells us whether the user actually has a hi-priority booking_code.

```sql
SELECT
    guests.name AS name,
    reservations.booking_code AS code,
    COALESCE(reservations.booking_code = guests.booking_code, 0) AS has_good
FROM
    reservations
JOIN
    guests ON
        reservations.booking_code = guests.booking_code OR
        reservations.booking_code = guests.parent_booking_code
```

COALESCE is here so that if guests.booking_code is NULL, the result of the expression is 0 and not NULL. In your DBMS COALESCE might be called ISNULL or IFNULL.

Let's now GROUP it BY code, and select max(has_good). Let's not select the guest name, since we don't need it yet. What it gives us is that we know now for each code whether there is a high-pri user for that code or not:

```sql
SELECT
    reservations.booking_code AS code,
    MAX(COALESCE(reservations.booking_code = guests.booking_code, 0)) AS has_good
FROM
    reservations
JOIN
    guests ON
        reservations.booking_code = guests.booking_code OR
        reservations.booking_code = guests.parent_booking_code
GROUP BY code;
```

With this information we can now change the original query a little bit, so that if there is a guest that has a hi-pri booking for a given code, we will choose such a guest, otherwise we choose any guest:

```sql
SELECT
    MIN(guests.name) AS name,
    reservations.booking_code AS code
FROM
    reservations
JOIN
    guests ON
        reservations.booking_code = guests.booking_code OR
        reservations.booking_code = guests.parent_booking_code
JOIN (
    SELECT
        reservations.booking_code AS code,
        MAX(COALESCE(reservations.booking_code = guests.booking_code, 0)) AS has_good
    FROM
        reservations
    JOIN
        guests ON
            reservations.booking_code = guests.booking_code OR
            reservations.booking_code = guests.parent_booking_code
    GROUP BY code
) AS availability ON availability.code = reservations.booking_code
WHERE availability.has_good = COALESCE(reservations.booking_code = guests.booking_code, 0)
GROUP BY code;
```

Note how this query is just the query from your last question, joined against the subquery that we built above. It then filters out users, that don't have a high-priority booking code, if the code is known to have at least one user who does have it.

I tested it on your sample dataset, I believe it should work in the general case.

EDIT: Author asked in the comments if one can get rid of one of the reservations tables in the JOIN. It is possible indeed, here is a slightly modified query that only selects from reservations once:

```sql
SELECT
    MIN(guests.name) AS name,
    availability.code AS code
FROM
(
    SELECT
        reservations.booking_code AS code,
        MAX(COALESCE(reservations.booking_code = guests.booking_code, 0)) AS has_good
    FROM
        reservations
    JOIN
        guests ON
            reservations.booking_code = guests.booking_code OR
            reservations.booking_code = guests.parent_booking_code
    GROUP BY code
) AS availability
JOIN
    guests ON
        availability.code = guests.booking_code OR
        availability.code = guests.parent_booking_code
WHERE availability.has_good = COALESCE(availability.code = guests.booking_code, 0)
GROUP BY code;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed steps and explanation. We tried your code and found out that for the `MAX(COALESCE())` part, we actually have to use `MAX(COALESCE(reservations.booking_code = guests.booking_code, FALSE)::integer)`. Also the last `GROUP BY` needs to be expanded into `GROUP BY reservations.booking_code` on our side. Anyway, we'll try to integrate this into our current query and see how we can get it working.

Comment: I noticed that you're doing `JOIN` between `guests` and `reservations` twice. Is it possible to do it only once (outside or inside doesn't matter), since in our actual code we're also doing `JOIN` with multiple other tables to get the `booking_code` we're looking for? (We'll try it here as well)

Comment: Looks like we're able to remove one JOIN by using: `JOIN ( SELECT CASE WHEN booking_code IS NULL then parent_booking_code ELSE booking_code END AS code, CASE WHEN booking_code IS NULL then 0 ELSE 1 END AS has_good FROM guests) AS availability ON availability.code = reservations.booking_code`. Now we just need to check if the results are as expected.

Comment: @Sutandiono, yes, indeed, one of the reservations doesn't need to be in the query, see the EDIT at the end of my answer, where I removed it. You will still need to do the adjustment to the COALESCE call that you described above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
with cte as (
SELECT
      guests.name AS name,
      guests.combo_code AS code,
      MIN(guests.ranking) AS rank
FROM
      reservations
JOIN
(SELECT 
    COALESCE (booking_code, parent_booking_code) AS combo_code,
    CASE WHEN booking_code IS NOT NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 2
    END AS ranking,
    guests.*
 FROM guests
) AS guests ON
    guests.combo_code = reservations.booking_code
GROUP BY name, code
ORDER BY rank, name
) , cte2 as (
select code,min(rank) as rank from cte group by code 
)
select name,cte.code,cte.rank from cte inner join cte2 on cte.rank=cte2.rank where   
cte.rank=cte2.rank and cte.code=cte2.code
```

Comment: We're actually trying to avoid CTE as in the original problem, we're doing JOIN on multiple tables, and so far we haven't been able to simplify it based on your example. However, we'll try to see if we can rearrange some of our original code to cater for this.